# Cutting off a function

Tags: python, sudoku, nonetype

I am trying to make the function cut off when there is a `NoneType` occurring but it continues to cut off even when there isn't a `NoneType`.

```
def solver(integer):
    try:
        i  = integer.index(0)
    except ValueError:
        return integer

    used_integer = [integer[j] for j in range(81)
        if not ((i-j)%9 * (i//9^j//9) * (i//27^j//27 | (i%9//3^j%9//3)))]

    for j in range(1, 10):
        if j not in used_integer:
            solved_sudoku = solver(integer[:i]+[j]+integer[i+1:])

            if solved_sudoku is not None:
                return solved_sudoku

        if j in used_integer:
            sys.exit('Error')
```

065000008
700860400
000020009
040001002
000207000
300500070
400050000
001079003
9000002**66** <-------**Sudoku puzzle with duplicate values**

When I do this I receive an error from the class

```
class Sudoku(list):

def __init__(self, content):

     list.__init__(self, [int(i) for i in content.split()]

     if isinstance(content, str) else content)

def __str__(self):

     return '\n'.join(

          ' '.join([(str(j) if j != 0 else '-')

                for j in self[i*9:(i+1)*9]]) for i in range(9))
```

I get the error (TypeError: NoneType object is not iterable

Comment: What programming language is this? You should tag it.

Comment: Its python my bad its my first question

Comment: @user2981626 I have attempted to clean up the formatting of your code; please make sure that it accurately reflects your own code and modify if necessary.

Comment: No, the Solved_Sudoku is being referenced before its declared

Comment: What does the input to this function (the `integer`) look like? More generally, instead of describing the behavior in vague terms, can you give us some inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs so we can understand where it's going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You almost certainly don't want to use `sys.exit()` in the manner in which you are using it - that will instantly terminate *all* of your code, meaning that you'll never be able to go back up the call chain or even just try a different iteration of the loop.

Perhaps you want `continue` instead, to try another iteration of the loop?

Comment: Well its reading a sudoku puzzle from a file earlier on so if there is an error I want the program to stop and print an error message

Comment: @user2981626: Raising an exception will stop and print an error message, with a useful traceback that will help you during debugging. Once you've got things working, you can always wrap a `try`/`except` around the main function call to handle that exception by printing something nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if solved_sudoku:
    return solved_sudoku
```

Comment: You should almost _never_ use `!= False`. Especially with a function that just documents that it returns a false value, rather than `False`.